# Find users most frequent recommandations based on input queries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a `input query` table in the following:

```
    query
0  orange
1   apple
2    meat
```

which I want to make against the `user query` table as following

```
   user       query
0    a1      orange
1    a1  strawberry
2    a1        pear
3    a2      orange
4    a2  strawberry
5    a2       lemon
6    a3      orange
7    a3      banana
8    a6        meat
9    a7        beer
10   a8       juice
```

Given a query in `input query`, I want to match it to query by other user in `user query` table, and return the top 3 ranked by total number of counts.

For example,
`orange` in `input query`, it matches user `a1`,`a2`,`a3` in `user query` where all have queried `orange`, other items they have query are `strawberry` (count of 2), `pear`, `lemon`, `banana` (count of 1).

The answer will be `strawberry` （since it has max count), `pear`, `lemon` (since we only return top 3).

Similar reasoning for `apple` (no user query therefore output 'nothing') and `meat` query.

So the final `output table` is

```
    query   recommend
0  orange  strawberry
1  orange        pear
2  orange       lemon
3   apple     nothing
4    meat     nothing
```

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Create sample dataframes
df_input = pd.DataFrame( {'query': {0: 'orange', 1: 'apple', 2: 'meat'}} )
df_user = pd.DataFrame( {'user': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a1', 2: 'a1', 3: 'a2', 4: 'a2', 5: 'a2', 6: 'a3', 7: 'a3', 8: 'a6', 9: 'a7', 10: 'a8'}, 'query': {0: 'orange', 1: 'strawberry', 2: 'pear', 3: 'orange', 4: 'strawberry', 5: 'lemon', 6: 'orange', 7: 'banana', 8: 'meat', 9: 'beer', 10: 'juice'}} )

target_users = df_user[df_user['query'].isin(df_input['query'])]['user']
mask_users=df_user['user'].isin(target_users)
mask_queries=df_user['query'].isin(df_input['query'])
df1=df_user[mask_users & mask_queries]
df2=df_user[mask_users]
df=df1.merge(df2,on='user').rename(columns={"query_x":"query", "query_y":"recommend"})
df=df[df['query']!=df['recommend']]
df=df.groupby(['query','recommend'], as_index=False).count().rename(columns={"user":"count"})
df=df.sort_values(['query','recommend'],ascending=False, ignore_index=False)
df=df.groupby('query').head(3)
df=df.drop(columns=['count'])
df=df_input.merge(df,how='left',on='query').fillna('nothing')
df
```

Where `df` is the result. Is there any way to make the code more concise?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a particular reason to favor pears over bananas (since they both count for one), I would suggest a more idiomatic way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_input = pd.DataFrame(...)
df_user = pd.DataFrame(...)

df_input = (
    df_input
    .assign(
        recommend=df_input["query"].map(
            lambda x: df_user[
                (df_user["user"].isin(df_user.loc[df_user["query"] == x, "user"]))
                & (df_user["query"] != x)
            ]
            .value_counts(subset="query")
            .index[0:3]
            .to_list()
            if x in df_user["query"].unique()
            else "nothing"
        )
    )
    .explode("recommend")
    .fillna("nothing")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(df_input)
# Output
    query   recommend
0  orange  strawberry
1  orange      banana
2  orange       lemon
3   apple     nothing
4    meat     nothing
```